# Possible rounding issue in program

Tags: java

I spent all night writing this code for my class, it's damn near done, but one of my output values (com2) is $.10 off what it should be and I have absolutely no idea why. 
I'm going to paste the entire program, let me know if you guys have any suggestions! :)

GOAL OUTCOME:

```
Salesperson: GARY
Tier: B
Base Salary: $ 800.89
Commission 1: $ 1200.00
Commission 2: $ 152.28
Total Commission: $ 1352.28
Monthly Salary: $ 2153.17
```

MY CURRENT OUTCOME:

```
Salesperson: GARY
Tier: B
Base Salary: $    800.89 
Commission 1: $   1200.00 
Commission 2: $    152.18 
Total Commision: $   1352.18 
Monthly Salary: $   2153.07
```

If you guys would be so kind to run this program use this data for the laptops:

```
Basic: 0
Premium: 12
Deluxe: 0
```

Code:

```
    /*
* To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
* To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/
package lab2.gsmith;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


/**
*
* @author gskil
*/
public class Lab2Gsmith {
private static final Set<String> 
        validOptions = new HashSet<>    (Arrays.asList("Yes","YES","No","no","Y","y","N","n"));
private static final Set<String> 
        yValues = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("Yes","YES","Y","y"));

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

// ***************** DECLARE VARAIBLES ********************
String input;
String addAnother = null;
String tier = null;
String name = null;
String pString = null;




double bCost = 650.90;
double pCost = 950.50;
double dCost = 1350.95;
int bCom = 50;
int pCom = 100;
int dCom = 150;
int bSales = 0;
int pSales = 0;
int dSales = 0;
double totalSales;
double baseSal = 0;
double com1;
double totalCom;
int bonus = 0;
double com2 = 0;
double monthlySal;






// ***************** GET INPUT ****************************
do{

do{

input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your name?");  
if (input.matches("[a-zA-Z]+")) 

    name = input.toUpperCase();
else

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog
    (null,"Please enter a valid name containing: ‘a-z’ or ‘A-Z’ lower or upper case\n");

}
while (!input.matches("[a-zA-Z]+"));


do{

input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What tier are you?");  
if (input.matches("[a-cA-C]+"))  

    tier = input.toUpperCase();
else

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog
    (null,"Please enter a valid tier: ‘a’-‘c’, lower or upper case\n");
}

while (!input.matches("[a-cA-C]+"));            


do{

input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your base salary?");
if (input.matches("[0-9$.]+"))

    baseSal = Double.parseDouble(input);
else

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog
    (null,"Please enter a valid salary amount containing: ‘0’-‘9’, and/or beginning ‘$’, and/or ‘.’\n");
}
while (!input.matches("[0-9$.]+"));


do{

input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many basic laptops did you sell?");
if (input.matches("[0-9]+"))  

    bSales = Integer.parseInt(input);
else

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog
    (null,"Please enter a valid number: Only positive integers\n");
}
while (!input.matches("[0-9]+")); 


do{
input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many premium laptops did you sell?");
if (input.matches("[0-9]+"))  

    pSales = Integer.parseInt(input);
else

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog
    (null,"Please enter a valid number: Only positive integers\n");
}
while (!input.matches("[0-9]+"));        


do{
input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many deluxe laptops did you sell?");
if (input.matches("[0-9]+"))  

    dSales = Integer.parseInt(input);
else

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog
    (null,"Please enter a valid number: Only positive integers\n");
}
while (!input.matches("[0-9]+"));        



    // ******************** PROCESSING ************************
totalSales = ((bSales * bCost) + (pSales * pCost) + (dSales * dCost));

if (totalSales > 2500){
    com2 = 0.00;

if (totalSales >= 2500 && totalSales < 5500)
    com2 = (totalSales * 0.01);

if (totalSales >= 5500 && totalSales < 10500)
    com2 = (((totalSales - 5500) * 0.02) + 75);

if (totalSales >= 10500 && totalSales < 13500)
    com2 = (((totalSales - 10500) * 0.03) + 125);

if (totalSales > 13500)
    com2 = 375;
}


switch (tier){

    case "A":
        if (com2 > (.75 * baseSal))
            pString = ("Congratulations, " + name + (", you have been promoted to tier B."));
        else
            pString = ("Sorry, " + name + (", you have not been promoted this month."));
        break;

    case "B":
        if (com2 > (.75 * baseSal))
            pString = ("Congratulations, " + name + (", you have been promoted to tier C."));
        else
            pString = ("Sorry, " + name + (", you have not been promoted this month."));
        break;

    case "C":
        if (com2 > (.75 * baseSal))
            pString = ("Congratulations, " + name + (", you have earned a $1000 bonus!"));
        else
            pString = ("Sorry, " + name + (", you have not earned a bonus this month."));
        break;
    }

if ("C".equals(tier) && com2 > (.75 * baseSal))
    bonus = 1000;
else 
    bonus = 0;




// ***************** DO CALCULATIONS **********************

com1 = (bCom * bSales) + (pCom * pSales) + (dCom * dSales);

totalCom = (com1 + com2);

monthlySal = (baseSal + totalCom + bonus);





// ***************** SHOW OUTPUT **************************
System.out.println("Salesperson: " + name);
System.out.println("Tier: " + tier);
System.out.printf("Base Salary: $%10.2f \n", baseSal);
System.out.printf("Commission 1: $%10.2f \n", com1);
System.out.printf("Commission 2: $%10.2f \n", com2);
System.out.printf("Total Commision: $%10.2f \n", totalCom);
System.out.printf("Monthly Salary: $%10.2f \n", monthlySal);
System.out.println("\n\n" + pString + "\n");

while (true) {
addAnother = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Would you like to enter another salespersons' data?");

if (validOptions.contains(addAnother)) {
    break;
}

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please enter a valid answer: Yes, YES, No, no, Y, y, N, n\n");
}


    }while (yValues.contains(addAnother));
}

}
```

Comment: float/double are not suitable for representing currency as you can't represent the fractions accurately in binary - use BigDecimal.

Comment: It's time to learn how to use debugger, and walk through iterations..

Comment: @BarrySW19 Thanks for your answer! I've read that before but I'm not quite sure how to use BigDecimal yet.

Comment: Start with an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Input and output dialogs are irrelevant to this particular problem. Everything besides `com2` calculation is irrelevant. Also where does `152.28` value come from?

Comment: As per logic implemented, calculated value of `com2` will be `152.18` only, no issue due to rounding. check the logic if it is correctly implemented

Comment: @user3207158 Yeah I'm sorry. I just started learning how to use java. If I can't ask my professor or TA, then I bring it here.

Comment: @GregSmith Aha I just did the calculation on paper only to find out 152.28 is the correct value

Comment: @user3207158 Could you explain how you came to get 152.28?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commission 2: $ 152.18 is correct.
Check the code:

```
com2 = (((totalSales - 10500) * 0.03) + 125);
```

(((11406.0- 10500) * 0.03) + 125) = **152.18** //GOAL Commission 2: $ 152.28 is incorrect.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't even think to check the actual values, I thought it had something to do with my program. If that's the case I'm going to say it was a printing error on my professor's part. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

For 12 premium sales with `double pCost = 950.50;` you get a `totalSum` of 11406. This means you use the following calculation for `com2`:

```
if (totalSales >= 10500 && totalSales < 13500)
    com2 = (((totalSales - 10500) * 0.03) + 125);
```

This evaluates to 152.18.

Now what would `totalSales` have to be for it to result in 152.28?

```
(152.28 - 125)/0.03 + 10500 = 27.28/0.03 + 10500 
                            = 909,3333333333 + 10500
                            = 11.409,33333333333
```

So the price of one laptop would be `11.409,33333333333/12` and that could never evaluate to a correct currency value. So if you're variables are set correctly, 152.28 could not be a correct result.

So I would conclude either your combination of input and output is wrong or some parameters are not set correctly. My guess would be that it is a typo in the GOAL section, and com2 should indeed be your result of 152.18.